# "An object reference is required for the non-static field,method,or property ' RxCard.dataobjects.Pharmacy.Area.Get' "

Tags: c#

I have a custom validation attribute that I need to pass in some properties to. However, my problem occurs when applying the attribute itself. I'm learning .net backwards so I tend to get stuck on the "simpler" problems. I already tried making the property a static but that messed up parts of my view. How can I approach this? 
Attribute:

```
  public class MinimumPhoneDigits : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public string[] _properties;
        public int _expectedsize;
        public MinimumPhoneDigits(int expectedsize, params string[] properties)
        {
            ErrorMessage = "Not the expected size!";
            _properties = properties;
            _expectedsize = expectedsize;
        }
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (_properties == null || _properties.Length < 1)
            {
                return new ValidationResult("WOAH! Not the right size.");
            }
            int totalsize = 0;

            foreach (var property in _properties)
            {
                var propinfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(property);

                if (propinfo == null)
                    return new ValidationResult(string.Format("could not find {property}"));

                var propvalue = propinfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null) as string;

                if (propvalue == null)
                    return new ValidationResult(string.Format("wrong property for {property}"));

                totalsize += propvalue.Length;

            }
            if (totalsize != _expectedsize)
                return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
```

class:

```
    public class Pharmacy
        {                               
            [MinimumPhoneDigits(10, Area)] 
            public string PhoneNumber
            {
                get
                {
                    return _phoneNumber;
                }
                set
                {
                    _phoneNumber = value;
                }
            }      
            private string _phoneNumber;
            public string Area
            {
                get
                {
                    try
                    {
                        return _phoneNumber.Split(new char[] { '(', ')', '-' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0].Trim();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        return "";
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: where is your custom attribute actually defined?

Comment: You need to show us where you are getting `Pharmacy.Area` but, in general, `catch { return ""; }` is a member of the problem set, not of the solution set.

Comment: Your code is swallowing any exception that is thrown, btw.

Comment: Can you include the line of code where the error is occurring? Sounds like you might be doing `something = Pharmacy.Area;`, invoking the (non-`static`) getter through the class rather an an object instance of the class, like `Pharmacy pharm = new Pharmacy(); something = pharm.Area;`

Comment: The error occurs when declaring "Area" in [MinimumPhoneDigits(10,Area) @BobKaufman.

Comment: the attribute is defined outside the pharmacy class @SamIam.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attributes are design-time.  You can't pass values that are only known at runtime like `Area`

I think you might actually be intending to pass a string, like this

```
[MinimumPhoneDigits(10, "Area")]
```

Comment: Should I apply jquery validation on these fields then? Basically I have 3 textboxes for a phone number. One for area, prefix, suffix...and I'm trying to validate that the sum of the 3 fields is 10 before submitting.

Comment: you were absolutely correct. I completely overlooked that . I still haven't been able to trigger the validation but the quotations got rid of the problem. Thank you.